# Django custom method won't show up

Tags: python, django, object, methods, django-models

I have two custom methods for a model manager in Django.  One of them works.  I recently added another and Django (and python) act like it doesn't exist.  Here's the relevant part of the model:

```
class FigureServerManager(models.Manager):
    #This method takes as input a user and grabs a figure that is not marked complete for which that user has not already submitted a result
    def serve_to_user(self,user):
    not_complete=super(FigureServerManager, self).get_query_set().filter(complete=0)
    for Figure in not_complete:
        checkifresult=User.objects.get(pk=user).result_set.all().filter(figure=Figure.id)
    if not checkifresult:
            return Figure

    #This is a copy of the above method that I want to change to do something else, but I can't even get it to show up yet
    def serve_training_task(self, user):
        with_correct_ans=super(FigureServerManager, self).get_query_set().filter(complete=0)
        for Figure in with_correct_ans:
            checkifresult=User.objects.get(pk=user).result_set.all().filter(figure=Figure.id)
        if not checkifresult:
                return Figure

class Figure(models.Model):
    doi=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='classify')
    complete=models.BooleanField()
    #include the default manager    
    objects=models.Manager()
    #add the extra one for serving figures
    serve_objects=FigureServerManager()
```

I get an error on the website (running the Django development server) like this:

```
'FigureServerManager' object has no attribute 'serve_training_task'
```

and if I run dir(FigureServerManager) in python the serve_training_task method does not appear but the serve_to_user method does appear.  Why doesn't serve_training_task work?

Comment: you have a mix of tabs and spaces which is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Python Language Reference, §2.1.8: "Indentation"](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

Comment: I copied and pasted the leading whitespace from the working code to the non-working code and that got it working.  Thanks.  I'm writing this in gedit (a beginner, can you tell?) - is there a better way to write python where there are at least some visual cues to let me know about problems like this?  Right now it is totally opaque to me.

Comment: Unfortunately no editor is psychic and can realize that you meant a method versus a module-level function. This is something that you will have to acquire experience in over time.